# Enabled flags in Chrome Canary, but still cant use Es6 modules

Tags: google-chrome, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I want to use es6 modules like `import Foo from './foo'` natively in chrome. However after enabling all the recommended flags (and then some), it does not work.

I read that hosting it from a web server can help, but that did not fix it. I have played with the flags quite a bit and tried it on Chrome Stable, Beta, and Canary.

`Unexpected 'import'` error!

Comment: Are you loading the script with `type="module"`?

Comment: Sure am. I would like to avoid using ES5 OOP or transpilers. Es6 classes work fine.